# Use custom class in Symfony 2

Tags: class, symfony

How can i use custome class in SYmfony 2 ?

I created class `"Social"` where i defined the namespace `"namespace W4Pro\Social Bundle\Class"` and located in directory `"W4Pro\SocialBundle\Class"`. Now i want to use this class in my controller `"W4Pro\SocialBundle\Controller\DefaultController"`, i used this `"use W4Pro\SocialBundle\Class\Social;"` but when i run the page i received the error

```
Cannot import resource "C:\xampp1\htdocs\test\src\W4Pro\SocialBundle/Controller/" from "C:/xampp1/htdocs/test/app/config\routing.yml". (Class W4Pro\SocialBundle\Controller\Social does not exist)
```

Comment: ok solved ;) I changed directory Class to Custom ;)

Comment: Yeah, as you've discovered, `Class` is a reserved keyword in PHP so avoid them if you can. I had a simular issue with a class called `Trait` which was fine until I upgrade to PHP 5.4 :D Full list is here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php